# Hanging PostgreSQL Processes

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jboss

We are running a Java EE web application in JBoss that is using PostgreSQL 8.0.9 as the database.

One page in the application runs a big and complicated query when it is loaded. We had a problem that manifested if a user requested this page and closed their browser window before the requested page was returned to the client. The problem was that the closing of the window would spawn a new PostgreSQL thread/process (viewable via top) and the new thread/process would take a long time to switch from SELECT to idle in the top output. If approximately 5 or more users did this (closed the browser window before the large complicated query page returned to the client) in a small window of time the spawned threads/processes were growing and not switching to idle (staying in SELECT) and consuming a lot of CPU, causing major performance problems. It is important to mention that if the users that closed the browser window logged out, the associated thread/process would switch to idle and the CPU use would decrease. It is also important to mention that if JBoss was restarted the applicable threads/processes would switch to idle (as all the users would be logged out by the restart).

The problem of the hanging threads/processes seems to have been resolved by a database backup and RESTORE. Now the new threads/processes that are spawned are switched from SELECT to idle in a generally short period of time and the CPU is not burdened by them as much. Also, performance on large complicated queries in general seems to have improved significantly since the RESTORE.

We run VACUUM every 24 hours on the database. We do not run REINDEX on the database because of data corruption risks. We do tend to have rather high await numbers on iostat outputs, especially in the performance problem cases described above.

What happens to a database when it is dumped and restored (ex. REINDEX, etc.)? Which one of these seems to be the key to our solution?

Is there a setting that manages the number of threads/processes that are spawned when browser windows are closed before a page with a large complicated query is returned to the client? Is there a setting to manage the transition of threads/processes like this from SELECT to idle?  Is there away to manage either of these at the application level?

Answer (score 2):

Version 8.0 is already EOL and version 8.0.9 hasn't been patched in a long time as well: 8.0.26 has been the last. You are missing many patches and should at least update to the latest 8.0-version, but also start a migration to a version that is still supported. Since version 8.2 and 8.3, performance has become much better.

Question: Why do you think REINDEX corrupts your data? Corruption of data would make this statement pretty useless... REINDEX is not something you would do every day, but sometimes you need it.

Comment: Frank, thanks for your reply. Our goal is to get to another version of PostgreSQL, but we are not there yet. We are trying to figure out something that we can do now while we are working on getting the application ready for the new PostgreSQL version. As for a REINDEX, we see a lot of postings PostgreSQL forum and elsewhere on web from people that were running REINDEX and had something go wrong. Perhaps these people did not run REINDEX correctly and had their data corrupted.

Comment: An update to version 8.0.26 is not a big deal, just do the installation and a restart using pg_ctl. That's it. You do make a backup before, but that's normal. An upgrade to the latest 8.2-release is also not a huge project, 8.3 and later might have a bigger impact because of changes. Check the release notes to see if a patch did solve your hanging proces problem.